# Modern UI application design for Windows Form Application

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio

Ok it's been a long time when I last developed a `Windows Form Application` but today I am doing it again.

The thing what I see is that Win Form still uses those old style UI tools like button etc. for its application however Microsoft and Windows have changed their design language quite a bit to flat Metro/Modern UI.

**So My Question is there a way to make use to newly style tools for Windows Form Applications? Preferably without using any 3rd party plugin?**

I am working with `.Net4.5`, On `Windows 8.1` with `VS 2012.`

Comment: If you want your application to have a "Modern UI" look then you should be looking at WPF and using XAML to define the UI.

Comment: Love me some Telerik tools

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two ways to do this.

1. If you want to stick on with Win Form Applications, then just change the buttons and controls to flat style in properties and for button, place flat Metro style icons images that suit your application. I am currently doing that to give a new look to my existing application.
2. As said in the comment, if you are ready to design a whole new application, the WPF is the best choice. If you are targeting the Windows Store, then make use of [Blend for Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj171012%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It will assist you in creating professional Windows 8 Applications.

Answer (score 7):

A better option if you are sticking with WinForms is to use a ModernUI framework to help out. See https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetroModernUI/ for details on a framework that makes it easy.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, there is another way that you can do it.

If you are familiar with playing with properties of control and the use of panel control then its so easy than using any other 3rd party (framework).

I have created sample test using flat design without any 3rd Party Window form design that uses Modern flat Design without 3rd part.

[image: example]

Comment: You should elaborate to show the technical parts of this answer.