# visual studio 2012 winforms new flat layout

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012

new to VS 2012-2013.
on win7

I was hoping to create a winform with the new flat layout, independent from windows version. 
I need a finish like this one

[new http://calmoni.com/225db3ab6565d132c3b4b3/new.png](http://calmoni.com/225db3ab6565d132c3b4b3/new.png)

as opposed to the old windows Dependant

[image: Imgur]

Is this part of Visual studio 2012-3 or do I have to create it from scratch by removing top bar and recreating buttons?

Answer (score 3):

This is tied to your windows version. You'd have to recreate it from scratch for windows forms, or if using WPF you could possibly find a style to apply for the new flat window style.  It would probably be easier in WPF to change the form's style.

edit:

WPF NuGet package:

[Modern UI for WPF](http://mui.codeplex.com/)

[Answer for Winforms from previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161213/modern-ui-application-design-for-windows-form-application)

Answer (score 3):

Try here, you might find what you want:

http://mui.codeplex.com/

http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/

Answer (score 0):

as i think you wanna create a castum form and that is very easy and i made it as you see in da pic....all you have to do is make the flatstyle of da form is "none"

and drag a panel from da tool box a make it dock up and make it color darker than da color of da form and put 3 buttons (close , maximize , minimize) and write thier codes but sorry i dont remember them you van search.....then you have to put some codes to move da form when you click and move da panel you put and da codes is 2 parts

1- varibless

2- normal codes

```
1- the varilbels
==================
Public Class your_form
    Dim x, y As Integer
    Dim newpoint As New System.Drawing.Point
===============================================
2-normal codes
     Private Sub Panel1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseDown
        x = Control.MousePosition.X - Me.Location.X
        y = Control.MousePosition.Y - Me.Location.Y
    End Sub
    Private Sub Panel1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseMove
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            newpoint = Control.MousePosition
            newpoint.X -= (x)
            newpoint.Y -= (y)
            Me.Location = newpoint
        End If
    End Sub
=======================================
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RDDx.png)